# cannot find shared library when library already in /usr/local/lib

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

At first I use `-L../` flag to specified the `.so` file in `../`. While it didn't work, I copy the library to `/usr/local/lib/`, delete the `-L` flag, recompile, and it still didn't work. Here is my `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -Wall -I../src/ -L../

all:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) example.cpp -o example -ltest
```

The library file call `libtest.so` and placed in `../`, and it compiled successfully, but I got `error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when running it in both situations.

Comment: Please consider adding additional descriptive tags to your question. Maybe [gcc], [linux], etc.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by your program to search for directories containing the libraries after it has been successfully compiled and linked.

So, if you set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/where/your/library/is:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

the program should run.